# JSON get nested information

Tags: json

I need to get information from some JSON code, so the data I have is:

```
{
        "lastUpdate": "2018-07-24T18:23:44.7530145",
        "ownerTeam": "Administradores",
        "createdDate": "2015-03-23T03:00:00",
        "baseStatus": "New",
        "status": "Novo",
        "urgency": "0.Baixa",
        "subject": "SPED PIS E COFINS",
        "id": 6408,
        "owner": {
            "id": "99",
            "personType": 1,
        }
 }
```

I would like to get the nested information outside the nest, for example the "personType". Like this:

```
{
        "lastUpdate": "2018-07-24T18:23:44.7530145",
        "ownerTeam": "Administradores",
        "createdDate": "2015-03-23T03:00:00",
        "baseStatus": "New",
        "status": "Novo",
        "urgency": "0.Baixa",
        "subject": "SPED PIS E COFINS",
        "id": 6408,
        "personType": 1,
```

}

See that I removed the **"owner"** and **"id": "99"** tags but **"personType": 1** is still there. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: with which language you're manipulating the `JSON` ?

Comment: It can be done, but as @ths is asking, the method of which will vary on which language you are using.

Comment: @CodeMonkey the OP's didn't mention the way he's manipulating this `JSON`, if he does so that will help us out.

Comment: Hello guys, I really have no experience in JSON. I got those data using filters with ODATA Protocol. Everything I do is to put some specific link on my browser and I get back the data. For example: https://api.example.com/public/v1/tickets?token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&$select=id,type,origin,status

Comment: @Innboy Again, unless we know how you are getting the data, I.E. what programming language and library you are using, we cannot help you. I gave you an example using JavaScript, but if you are not using that, then the method will change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing with JavaScript, you can easily do this.

```js
//Original JSON object
var j = {
  lastUpdate: '2018-07-24T18:23:44.7530145',
  ownerTeam: 'Administradores',
  createdDate: '2015-03-23T03:00:00',
  baseStatus: 'New',
  status: 'Novo',
  urgency: '0.Baixa',
  subject: 'SPED PIS E COFINS',
  id: 6408,
  owner: {
   id: '99',
    personType: 1,
  }
};
console.log(j);

//Set the personType in the root object
j.personType = j.owner.personType;
console.log(j);
//Remove the owner element from the object
delete j.owner;
console.log(j);
```